# piping grep regex into sed command

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I'm trying to create a script that will find/replace instances of a string matching:

```
vc/integer
```

The file /etc/securetty contains the following strings:

```
vc/1
vc/2
vc/3
vc/4
vc/5
vc/6
vc/7
vc/8
vc/9
vc/10
vc/11



grep -E 'vc/(\d{0,4}\D)*' /etc/securetty | while read line; do sed -ie "s=$line==g" /etc/securetty; done
```

As expected, the above command removes all the strings mentioned, but doesn't strip out the second digit, the 0 and the 1, which are a part of the last two strings, vc/1**0** vc/1**1**. I'm left with a file containing

```
0
1
```

How can I modify the command to remove a single and double digit match?

Comment: `grep -E 'vc/[0-9]+'`.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I get the same output.

Comment: Your command is quite convoluted. Why don't you simply delete with sed each line matching your grep pattern? Without `grep` and `while` I mean.

Comment: @xhienne Thanks, I've removed the `grep` and `while` pieces from the command.

Comment: I'm confused as to what matched the `\D` (non-digit character) in your nearly successful use shown in your question, especially since `\D` (or anything to serve in its place) is not included in the answer below, that you indicate works correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just do this simply?

```
sed -i -e 's|vc/[0-9]\{1,\}||g' /etc/security
```

## Explanation:

The `regex` `[0-9]\{1,\}` => 1 or more matches of the preceding atom, which in your case happens to be `[0-9]`. Note that `\d+` although equivalent to what I've given `[0-9]\{1,\}`, is not POSIX sed compliant. In the same vein, note that `[0-9]\{0,\}`  is equivalent to `\d*`.

Comment: That worked!  Could you please give me some info on how that command is working? Specifically, the `\{1,\}` part.